# Full height columns and sticky footer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, height, sticky-footer, ie8-compatibility-mode

Here is the code in question http://jsfiddle.net/svCg8/

I want the columns `#nav_one`, `#nav_two`, `#content` to be 100% tall.

Also it messed up on IE8 in compatibility mode.

Comment: The code you have put to jsfiddle, does not work in any browser.

Comment: what? it work perfectly here (chrome, safari, ff, ie8+). But i am trying to make the 3 columns 100% tall, so they will fill the entire remaining height of the viewport

Comment: Ah okay... yes the code works, but the 100% height not ^^ I thought that it is principally working, but just not in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the `height:auto !important;` - it is overriding all your other height settings due to the `important` addition:

http://jsfiddle.net/svCg8/1/